How to navigate to custom page for specific category from list view in flutterflow?
The main screen of the app has a ListView of different tasks (Icon associated with task, task name, address). Each task has a different name/category. When the parameters are passed on to the next page, it always displays the same layout of the page which is logical. What I would like to do is, I would like to have different page with different layout and information displayed based on the tasknam/category to which the task belongs.
For example when I have sneakers you want to have displayed size of the shoe, color but when you would have a hockey stick in the list view and you are passing the parameters you would like to see on the next page details as flex of the hockey stick, hand LH/RH, brand etc. from the same initial ListView. Is this even possible because all I see are apps that pass info from listView to the dame "detail page"?
I have looked at the conditional statement but having over 20+ categories this looks like very labor intensive thing to define trough dropdown menus which can be easily handled in other software trough default page layouts and assigned to category. I have search YouTube, your docs and was not able to find example on how to do this more sophisticated way?
Thanks for help.
I have trie conditional statements that are in practical.
I'm expecting from list view to a page that has custom layout and information based on what the category is not the standard same layout/design I get when I click on every item.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
